# Tree Json to Excel using Python

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

I have a JSON file with tree like structure, I want to convert it to excel format following the same tree like appearance. I tried `json_normalise` in `Python` and some other work around using Pandas but not getting the expected results. Please check my JSON file as below:

```
[
   {
      "Orgin":"SRO-31-202-277",
      "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1001",
      "Capasity":288.0,
      "Boite":"PEC-31-202-277-1001",
      "Child":[
         
      ],
      "Childs":[
         {
            "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1001",
            "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1023",
            "Capasity":72.0,
            "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1023",
            "Child":[
               {
                  "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1023",
                  "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1031",
                  "Capasity":12.0,
                  "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1031",
                  "Child":[
                     
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1023",
                  "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1024",
                  "Capasity":72.0,
                  "Boite":"PEC-31-202-277-1024",
                  "Child":[
                     {
                        "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1024",
                        "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1034",
                        "Capasity":36.0,
                        "Boite":"PEC-31-202-277-1034",
                        "Child":[
                           {
                              "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1034",
                              "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1035",
                              "Capasity":36.0,
                              "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1035",
                              "Child":[
                                 {
                                    "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1035",
                                    "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1036",
                                    "Capasity":36.0,
                                    "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1036",
                                    "Child":[
                                       {
                                          "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1036",
                                          "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1037",
                                          "Capasity":36.0,
                                          "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1037",
                                          "Child":[
                                             {
                                                "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1037",
                                                "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1038",
                                                "Capasity":36.0,
                                                "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1038",
                                                "Child":[
                                                   {
                                                      "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1038",
                                                      "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1039",
                                                      "Capasity":36.0,
                                                      "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1039",
                                                      "Child":[
                                                         
                                                      ]
                                                   }
                                                ]
                                             }
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           },
                           {
                              "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1034",
                              "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1040",
                              "Capasity":12.0,
                              "Boite":"PIA-31-202-277-1040",
                              "Child":[
                                 
                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1024",
                        "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1025",
                        "Capasity":72.0,
                        "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1025",
                        "Child":[
                           {
                              "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1025",
                              "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1026",
                              "Capasity":72.0,
                              "Boite":"PEC-31-202-277-1026",
                              "Child":[
                                 {
                                    "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1026",
                                    "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1027",
                                    "Capasity":72.0,
                                    "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1027",
                                    "Child":[
                                       {
                                          "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1027",
                                          "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1028",
                                          "Capasity":72.0,
                                          "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1028",
                                          "Child":[
                                             {
                                                "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1028",
                                                "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1029",
                                                "Capasity":12.0,
                                                "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1029",
                                                "Child":[
                                                   {
                                                      "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1029",
                                                      "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1030",
                                                      "Capasity":12.0,
                                                      "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1030",
                                                      "Child":[
                                                         
                                                      ]
                                                   }
                                                ]
                                             }
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1026",
                                    "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1033",
                                    "Capasity":12.0,
                                    "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1033",
                                    "Child":[
                                       
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           },
                           {
                              "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1025",
                              "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1032",
                              "Capasity":12.0,
                              "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1032",
                              "Child":[
                                 
                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1001",
            "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1041",
            "Capasity":24.0,
            "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1041",
            "Child":[
               {
                  "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1041",
                  "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1042",
                  "Capasity":24.0,
                  "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1042",
                  "Child":[
                     {
                        "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1042",
                        "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1043",
                        "Capasity":24.0,
                        "Boite":"PEC-31-202-277-1043",
                        "Child":[
                           {
                              "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1043",
                              "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1046",
                              "Capasity":12.0,
                              "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1046",
                              "Child":[
                                 
                              ]
                           },
                           {
                              "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1043",
                              "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1044",
                              "Capasity":24.0,
                              "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1044",
                              "Child":[
                                 {
                                    "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1044",
                                    "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1045",
                                    "Capasity":24.0,
                                    "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1045",
                                    "Child":[
                                       
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1001",
            "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1047",
            "Capasity":24.0,
            "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1047",
            "Child":[
               {
                  "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1047",
                  "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1048",
                  "Capasity":24.0,
                  "Boite":"PEC-31-202-277-1048",
                  "Child":[
                     {
                        "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1048",
                        "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1049",
                        "Capasity":24.0,
                        "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1049",
                        "Child":[
                           {
                              "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1049",
                              "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1050",
                              "Capasity":24.0,
                              "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1050",
                              "Child":[
                                 {
                                    "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1050",
                                    "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1053",
                                    "Capasity":12.0,
                                    "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1053",
                                    "Child":[
                                       
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1048",
                        "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1052",
                        "Capasity":12.0,
                        "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1052",
                        "Child":[
                           
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1047",
                  "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1051",
                  "Capasity":12.0,
                  "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1051",
                  "Child":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1001",
            "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1002",
            "Capasity":144.0,
            "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1002",
            "Child":[
               {
                  "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1002",
                  "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1003",
                  "Capasity":144.0,
                  "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1003",
                  "Child":[
                     {
                        "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1003",
                        "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1010",
                        "Capasity":96.0,
                        "Boite":"PIA-31-202-277-1010",
                        "Child":[
                           
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                        "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1003",
                        "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1004",
                        "Capasity":144.0,
                        "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1004",
                        "Child":[
                           {
                              "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1004",
                              "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1005",
                              "Capasity":144.0,
                              "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1005",
                              "Child":[
                                 {
                                    "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1005",
                                    "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1006",
                                    "Capasity":144.0,
                                    "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1006",
                                    "Child":[
                                       {
                                          "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1006",
                                          "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1007",
                                          "Capasity":144.0,
                                          "Boite":"PEC-31-202-277-1007",
                                          "Child":[
                                             {
                                                "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1007",
                                                "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1013",
                                                "Capasity":12.0,
                                                "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1013",
                                                "Child":[
                                                   {
                                                      "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1013",
                                                      "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1014",
                                                      "Capasity":12.0,
                                                      "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1014",
                                                      "Child":[
                                                         
                                                      ]
                                                   }
                                                ]
                                             },
                                             {
                                                "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1007",
                                                "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1008",
                                                "Capasity":144.0,
                                                "Boite":"PEC-31-202-277-1008",
                                                "Child":[
                                                   {
                                                      "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1008",
                                                      "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1015",
                                                      "Capasity":12.0,
                                                      "Boite":"PEC-31-202-277-1015",
                                                      "Child":[
                                                         {
                                                            "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1015",
                                                            "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1017",
                                                            "Capasity":12.0,
                                                            "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1017",
                                                            "Child":[
                                                               
                                                            ]
                                                         },
                                                         {
                                                            "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1015",
                                                            "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1016",
                                                            "Capasity":12.0,
                                                            "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1016",
                                                            "Child":[
                                                               
                                                            ]
                                                         }
                                                      ]
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                      "Orgin":"PEC-31-202-277-1008",
                                                      "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1009",
                                                      "Capasity":144.0,
                                                      "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1009",
                                                      "Child":[
                                                         {
                                                            "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1009",
                                                            "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1018",
                                                            "Capasity":12.0,
                                                            "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1018",
                                                            "Child":[
                                                               
                                                            ]
                                                         },
                                                         {
                                                            "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1009",
                                                            "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1019",
                                                            "Capasity":12.0,
                                                            "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1019",
                                                            "Child":[
                                                               {
                                                                  "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1019",
                                                                  "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1020",
                                                                  "Capasity":12.0,
                                                                  "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1020",
                                                                  "Child":[
                                                                     {
                                                                        "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1020",
                                                                        "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1021",
                                                                        "Capasity":12.0,
                                                                        "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1021",
                                                                        "Child":[
                                                                           
                                                                        ]
                                                                     },
                                                                     {
                                                                        "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1020",
                                                                        "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1022",
                                                                        "Capasity":12.0,
                                                                        "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1022",
                                                                        "Child":[
                                                                           
                                                                        ]
                                                                     }
                                                                  ]
                                                               }
                                                            ]
                                                         }
                                                      ]
                                                   }
                                                ]
                                             }
                                          ]
                                       },
                                       {
                                          "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1006",
                                          "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1012",
                                          "Capasity":12.0,
                                          "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1012",
                                          "Child":[
                                             
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           },
                           {
                              "Orgin":"PBO-31-202-277-1004",
                              "Cableid":"CDI-31-202-277-1011",
                              "Capasity":12.0,
                              "Boite":"PBO-31-202-277-1011",
                              "Child":[
                                 
                              ]
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

My expected result is in below snapshot.
**Expected result**
[image]

My current output excel.
**Current output**

[image]

Please Suggest, how can I achieve the result as expected.
Thank You.

Comment: Your screenshots appear very similar.  Maybe one needs to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a recursive function to flatten the complex structure to a list of dictionaries

Try the below, inserting your data into the "Childs" variable:

```py
import pandas as pd

Childs = [......]

def flatten_dict(childs):
    out = []
    if isinstance(childs, (list, tuple)):
        for elem in childs:
            out.extend(flatten_dict(elem))
    elif isinstance(childs, dict):
        sub_child = childs.pop('Child', [])
        out.append(childs)
        if sub_child:
            out.extend(flatten_dict(sub_child))
    return out

df = pd.DataFrame(flatten_dict(Childs))
```

You could then use pandas ".to_csv(<path>)" to write it to a csv file to open in Execl